# How do I configure keyboard commands?

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys, gedit, numlock

In Windows I never turn my NumLock on. I navigate through the page line with Home and End, and when I want to mark a line I use them in a combination with the Shift key. Pretty basic stuff right? Well I don't know how to do it in Ubuntu 10.04. The Home and End keys work but if I hold the Shift key it inputs respectively 7 and 1. If I turn the NumLock on it works but if I am not holding the Shift key it prints 7 and 1 again. Is there any way I can use my keyboard in Ubuntu the same way I do in Windows?

P.S. My roomy is much more experienced than me in Linux so he suggested that xmodmap might work, but even if this is the approach I should take, I still don't want to dig into the whole documentation, just the cliff notes for this exact task if you please.

Comment: Is this a laptop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **System** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard**, tab **Layout**, click on **Options**, go to **Miscellanous compatibility options** and then click on **Shift with numeric keypad keys works as in MS Windows**.

I don't have a numeric keypad so I can't test if it works but it should.

Answer (score -1):

i selected "Default numeric keypad keys", and it makes the system remember if numlock is on (ubuntu 12.10)

Comment: *Where* do you select this?